# Point Sub Domain to another Domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, dns, subdomain

We are creating a SAAS base application, where every company get its own subdomain. But if the company wants to configure another domain with our application, they can do that.

e.g. I am a company registered with the application www.mysaas.com, i got the subdomain "company.mysaas.com", now i want to point my "company.com" domain to the "company.mysaas.com", so how we can achieve this?

We want to create a custom domain configuration settings for the users of our application. Its like wordpress domain mapping (you can point your own domain to the wordpress site). So as i read related with wordpress they asked to add the CNAME of your site for the domain which you want to configure for mapping.

Our application is written in Codeigniter.

Is there any server configuration changes we need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean when you go to company.com you want to get rediected to company.mysaas.com?

Comment: Is each sub-domain running of one install of your application and you are just recognizing the sub-domain to serve up different content? Or are you actually making separate installs per client?